# Is debt to GDP ratio a misleading statistic to show the level of indebtedness of a government?

Tags: statistics, government-debt

The Debt to GDP ratio is a very popular statics to show the level of indebtedness of a government, so much that is even used in the [Euro convergence criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_convergence_criteria).
However its use seems misleading to me, since it does not account for interest rate or maturity.
I am correct that it is not a good statistics for this purpose? 
If yes, why is so popular?
Wouldn't an actualized value (by a rate common to the countries be compared) of future payments be a better statistic?

Answer (score 1):

It is good statistics for the level of debt country has.

What you describe is not level of debt. A country does not have higher *level* of debt just because debt has shorter maturity. Moreover, interest rate country pays is completely inconsequential for the *level* of debt.

What you probably mean is not *level* of debt, but *sustainability* of debt. For the sustainability of debt maturity and interest rate payments would actually matter. However, debt-to-GDP is not measure of debt sustainability so there is no reason to take these into account for the variable.

> I am correct that it is not a good statistics for this purpose?

No debt-to-GDP is accurate measure of debt *level* country has given the size of its economy. It is not a measure of debt sustainability, so one can't claim that having high debt-to-GDP, *necessarily*, is not sustainable for a country. However, if you just want to measure level of debt it is quite good measure.

> Wouldn't an actualized value (by a rate common to the countries be compared) of future payments be a better statistic?

Not if your intention is to measure actual debt level of a country. This would measure the discounted present value of the debt of the country, which might be useful for various purposes, but it is not a measure of debt level. Also, it would make sense to use the same rate for every country since discount rate will be almost certainly heterogenous for different countries.